# MacOs Chrome is returning Brasilia Summer Time from javascript's Date

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, date

When i parse dates from November 4th ahead, using javascript's new Date, GMT is set to -2 (Brasilia Summer Time --- the official is -3). The problem is that Brazil will not have a Summer Time this year.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming problem, it's a problem with the configuration of the operating system's DST rule.

Comment: ECMAScript Dates get host timezone information from the system itself, so check system settings.